# How to find worst-case big-O asymptotic running time?

Tags: runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

I need to be able to find the worst-case big-O asymptotic running time of a method. I'm reaching out here to see if anyone has any good references since I can't find any.

for example:

```
public void addEnd(double element)
{
    
    if (data.length == manyItems)
    ensureCapacity(manyItems*2 + 1);
    
    
    data[manyItems] = element;              
    currentIndex = manyItems;               
    manyItems++;                        
}
```

I'd need to figure out the running time of this method, but I don't know how.

I tried youtube, google, and all sorts of wesbites. I've gained some understanding, but I'm not confident enough to find the running time of a method.

Comment: Your function calls another function, `ensureCapacity()`. We need information about this function in order to compute the overall time complexity. So what do we know about it?

Answer (score 0):

As Berthur correctly points out, we can't know exactly what is going on without a definition for ensureCapacity. However, it is reasonable to infer here that ensureCapacity is an efficient method for redimensioning an array, which generally will allocate a new larger blob of memory and copy from the old to the new in time proportional to the size. If this is accurate, your worst-case runtime is O(n), where n is the current size of the collection.

In cases like this, though, what's called the amortized complexity is often brought up. To get amortized complexity, you consider the time complexity of performing the operation multiple times in some defined way. Here, consider the following use case: adding n elements to an initially empty collection with capacity equal to one. The runtime of each call goes like this:

```
call    T(n)     capacity
-------------------------
1       a        1
2       1b + a   3
3       a
4       3b + a   7
5       a
6       a
7       a
8       7b + a   15
...
not 2^k a
2^k     2^(k-1)b + a
```

If we now add up all these entries up to n = 2^m, we get:

```
T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(n) = an + (2n - 2 - log(n))b
                         = n(a + 2b) - b(2 + log(n))
```

And so, we see that this sequence of operations takes time linear in the final size of the collection, despite some individual operations taking linear times themselves. (Certainly if enough individual operations had taken linear time, the sum would have been proportional to n^2 instead of n).